# Como recuperar dados de um SUM com where diferente?

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela de horários de ponto de trabalho, que possui a `data_inicio`, `data_fim`, `usuario_id` e `extra` que indica se é hora extra ou não.

Eu já tenho uma query que traz a soma em segundos trabalhados por ano, mês, usuário dos últimos 6 meses.

Porém agora também preciso trazer a somatória de segundo trabalhados regulares e em horas extras (`extra` = 1).

```
SELECT 
        us.nome as usuario, 
        MONTH(tb.data_inicio) AS mes,
        YEAR(tb.data_inicio) AS ano,
        SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, tb.data_inicio, tb.data_fim)) AS total_segundos,
        COUNT(DISTINCT DAY(tb.data_inicio)) AS total_dias

FROM `horario_ponto` tb 

INNER JOIN `usuario` us ON us.id = tb.usuario_id 

WHERE tb.data_inicio > (LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY)

GROUP BY usuario, ano, mes
ORDER BY ano DESC, mes DESC, usuario ASC
```

Já tentei de diversas formas já parece não existir uma solução sem que a query tenha que ser reescrita dentro de uma subquery.

Existe alguma forma de:

`SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, tb.data_inicio, tb.data_fim)) AS total_segundos_regulares,` receber algum parametro que discrimine `tb.extra = 0` e num outro:

`SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, tb.data_inicio, tb.data_fim)) AS total_segundos_extra` receba o `tb.extra = 1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode somar com `IF` dentro de seus `SUM'S`.

```
SELECT  
        us.nome as usuario, 
        MONTH(tb.data_inicio) AS mes,
        YEAR(tb.data_inicio) AS ano,
        SUM(IF(extra = 0,TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, tb.data_inicio, tb.data_fim),0)) AS total_segundos_regulares,
        SUM(IF(extra = 1,TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, tb.data_inicio, tb.data_fim),0)) AS total_segundos_extras,
        COUNT(DISTINCT DAY(tb.data_inicio)) AS total_dias
FROM `horario_ponto` tb 
INNER JOIN `usuario` us ON us.id = tb.usuario_id 
WHERE tb.data_inicio > (LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY usuario, ano, mes
ORDER BY ano DESC, mes DESC, usuario ASC
```

Verifica os campos `extra` e soma em dois alias separados.